# VPC flow logs: Why does AWS exclude some traffic

Tags: amazon-vpc

I read the VPC flow logs blog post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/). It excludes traffic to Amazon DNS servers.
Also DHCP traffic is excluded and requests for instance metadata.

Just curious to know why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reach aws about it and they will just refer it as system limitation at this point and will be added as a road map